# Open Source Box.net using S3, RackCloud etc

Tags: user-interface, amazon-s3, data-storage

Wondering if anyone knows of an open source project which is basically box.net but using S3 or RackCloud or others. I have googled like I have never googled before and couldn't find anything. Tried different terms etc ... nothing.

I would love to host my own solution instead of paying $25 per user per month. We have a lot of users ... 100+ and yes they give us a discount but still pretty expensive.

Seems like something easy to build.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And....2 years later :)

http://owncloud.org/support/install/

http://pogoplug.com/

Comment: @Adam Evers, please, update your answer of choice :)

Answer (score -1):

Adam,

Your ninja searching skills are strong :)

No open source solution exists as an alternative to Box.net.  They have a solid and unique product for businesses and it would take a ton of developers to build from scratch the type of functionality that their product offers.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore. Please, update with OwnCloud, PogoPlug, and many others :(